# How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?

This is an example illustrating my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{letter}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | p{5cm} | }
\hline
Table header\\*
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat.
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere  
cubilia Curae. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat. 
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec   
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.  
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere  
cubilia Curae. \\
\hline
Table header\\*
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac   
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat.   
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis 
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec   
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.  
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae. \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have second header on page 3. I do not control table contents, so I can not do page breaks manually.

Comment: Just as an aside, you should look at the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for typesetting tables. It works with `longtable`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `longtable` package redefines `\hline` to allow pagebreaks by introducing penalties like `\penaly-\@lowpenalty` in the code. If I understand correctly, what you want is a variant of `\hline` which does not introduce any break point. To do this, you can just copy the code used to redefine `\hline` in `longtable.sty` and use it define a `\nobreakhline` variant macro in which the penalties have been changed to `10000` so as to prevent all pagebreaks. This gives the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{letter}

\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \penalty\@M
    \futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
\def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
  \ifx\@let@token\hline
    \global\let\@gtempa\@gobble
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}% <-- change here
  \else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@empty
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}% <-- change here
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
  \noalign{\LT@sep}%
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
  \noalign{\penalty\@M}%
  \@gtempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | p{5cm} | }
\hline
Table header\\*
\nobreakhline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat.
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere  
cubilia Curae. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat. 
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec   
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.  
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere  
cubilia Curae. \\
\hline
Table header\\*
\nobreakhline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra
porttitor turpis, id egestas neque congue in. Nam sed lorem lorem, ac   
tristique tellus. Nunc ornare feugiat orci, a blandit turpis facilisis ut.
Aenean pharetra ornare ante. Sed tempus leo in dolor eleifend placerat.   
Integer at enim augue. Ut nisl tortor, interdum ac porttitor ac, sagittis 
quis libero. Vivamus nibh metus, ornare vel pulvinar nec, fringilla nec   
orci. Maecenas mollis nulla a nibh fringilla nec convallis augue varius.  
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae. \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the detail of how the previous code works. It's between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because it's internal code containing the `@` character. The code is in two parts: it starts by defining the `\nobreakhline` which then calls another macro, `\LT@@nobreakhline`. The macro begins with

```
\def\nobreakhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
```

The `\ifnum..\fi` is a trick to make `TeX` that think that braces are correctly paired when they are not. It it thus equivalent to `\noalign{`, the closing brace being in the line beginning by `\ifnum` in the second macro. The macro then sets a penalty and calls the second macro thanks to a `\futurelet`:

```
    \penalty\@M
    \futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
```

This `\futurelet` is here to look ahead the `\nobreakhline` macro; as we will see, the behavior will not be the same if it's followed by another `\hline` or not.

We not get to the definition of `\LT@@nobreakhline`. It begins by an `if` test:

```
\def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
  \ifx\@let@token\hline
    \global\let\@gtempa\@gobble
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}% <-- change here
```

The test consists at looking if the next token is `\hline` or not. If it is, then the macro `\@gtempa` is set to `\@gobble`. As its name suggest, the `\@gobble` macros just gobbles the token following it. The macro `\@gtempa` is defined here but used at the end of `\LT@@nobreakhline` and so this means that `\LT@@nobreakhline` will gobble the `\hline` just following it, which avoids `\hline` to be typesetted twice. After setting `\@gtempa`, the macro `\LT@sep` is also set. That's the part which I changed from the original `longtable.sty` code: the penalty is changed from `-\@medpenalty` (which is something like `-151`, depending on the documentclass) to `\@M` (which is a shortcut for `10000`); this prevents any break to occur where the penalty is issued.

We now get to the `else` part of the conditional:

```
  \else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@empty
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}% <-- change here
  \fi
```

It has the same structure as the `then` part, except that it occurs only if our macro `\nobreakhline` is not followed by `\hline` and sets the ending macro `\@gtempa` to be noting (`\@empty`) meaning nothing special will be done at the end of `\LT@@nobreakhline`; there is also a penalty change to prevent breaking; this time the penalty was `-\@lowpenalty` (about -51) and is changed to `10000` as before. The next line is the "closing brace" mentioned before:

```
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
```

The next lines of codes typesets the rule:

```
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
```

Then the macro `\LT@sep` defined earlier is used, and it has the effect of preventing any breaks:

```
  \noalign{\LT@sep}%
```

Then there's another rule which is typesetted (it could probably be deleted from the code as we don't allow breaks any more, but it's harmless as it overlaps with the previous rule thanks to the negative `\vskip` in `\LT@sep`):

```
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
```

Finally, the macro ends with a penalty (to avoid another breaking point) and then the ending macro `\@gtempa` defined earlier is issued:

```
  \noalign{\penalty\@M}%
  \@gtempa}
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution of Philippe Goutet does not work well with `colortbl` package and setting the color of the horizontal line with `\arrayrulecolor`. Here is the solution that should work with `colortbl`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
 \penalty\@M
\futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
\def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
\ifx\LT@next\hline
  \global\let\LT@next\@gobble
 \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}}%
 \else
   \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
     \multispan\LT@cols{%
       \CT@drsc@\leaders\hrule\@height\doublerulesep\hfill}\cr}%
 \fi
\else
 \global\let\LT@next\empty
 \gdef\CT@LT@sep{%
   \noalign{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}%
\fi
\ifnum0=`{\fi}%
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\CT@LT@sep
\multispan\LT@cols
 {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}\cr
\noalign{\penalty\@M}%
\LT@next}
\makeatother
```