# How to disable pagebreak on \hline in supertabular?

Tags: page-breaking, rules, supertabular

This is similar to [How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6350/5763) but for `supertabular` or `xtab`: With `\tabularnewline\hline` I get pagebreaks (or in my case columnbreaks) *before* the hline, i.e. the hline appears at the top of the next column. I'm using [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration/14819#14819) to make `supertabular` work inside `multicols`.

How can I change this so that the hline is kept together with the row?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? Call me lazy, but I find it much easier to work with that piecing together code from different sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This takes the example in the question you cited and redefines supertab's `\\` to look ahead for `\hline` and suck it back before the page breaking code. this version doesn't take care if `\hline\hline` but could be extended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,supertabular,multicol}
\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\hline
\let\hline\relax
\loop\ifnum\n<300
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}&
                \hfill T\hfill\hfill F\hfill\hskip0pt\endgraf
                \vskip.5\baselineskip
                \color@begingroup
                \color{black!20}
                \hrule height3ex
                \color@endgroup
                \tabularnewline\hline
        }
\repeat
\makeatother
\let\hline\zz

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
        \if@firstcolumn
                \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
                \columnbreak
        \else
                \mcnewpage
        \fi
}

\let\savedST@cr\ST@cr
\def\ST@cr{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurelet\st@temp\ST@crhline}
\def\ST@crhline{%
  \ifx\st@temp\hline
    \global\let\next@a\hline
    \global\let\next@b\@gobble
  \else
    \global\let\next@a\@empty
    \global\let\next@b\@empty
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
\next@a
\savedST@cr
\next@b}

\makeatother
\tablehead{Item \#&\\}
\begin{supertabular}{lp{1.5in}}
\tablebody
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```