# Supertabular leaves header in next column

Tags: multicol, supertabular

I'm using supertabular in multicols enviroment  based on this thread's accepted answer [multicolumn long table or enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration). But there is sometimes header and empty table body left in new column/page (eg. when i change counter "n" to 19 - first column is full and only header is in second column). I've also tried this solution [How to disable pagebreak on \hline in supertabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34794/how-to-disable-pagebreak-on-hline-in-supertabular) but it doensn't help. Number of rows I create is arbitrary. Is there a way to remove these headers with no body (without removing all headers)?

EDIT: example

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{xcolor,supertabular,multicol}
    \newcount\n
    \n=0
    \def\tablebody{}
    \makeatletter
    \loop\ifnum\n<19
            \advance\n by1
            \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                    \textbf{\number\n.}&
                    \hfill T\hfill\hfill F\hfill\hskip0pt\endgraf
                    \vskip.5\baselineskip
                    \color@begingroup
                    \color{black!20}
                    \hrule height3ex
                    \color@endgroup
                    \tabularnewline
            }
    \repeat
    \makeatother
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
    \let\mcnewpage=\newpage
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\newpage{%
            \if@firstcolumn
                    \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
                    \columnbreak
            \else
                    \mcnewpage
            \fi
    }
    \makeatother
    \tablehead{Item \#&\\}
    \begin{supertabular}{lp{1.5in}}
    \tablebody
    \end{supertabular}
    \end{multicols*} 
    \end{document}
```