# Avoid midrule and hline together at head of supertabular

Tags: memoir, supertabular, hhline

I assume this is a duplicate but I couldn't find this precise problem here nor in the docs.

I am using `supertabular` to create a long table spanning multiple pages with `\midrule` after the head and`\hline` after each row.

Unfortunately, on the second page, the `\midrule` and the `\hline` are shown (see picture below), while I would like to have only the `\midrule` there, i.e. I would like to "skip" this particular `\hline`. Is that somehow possible.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \centering
        \tablefirsthead{\toprule Row Counter & Random Header \\ \arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}
        \tablehead{Row Counter & Random Header \\ \arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule    \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}
        \tabletail{ \\ \arrayrulecolor{black} \bottomrule \arrayrulecolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{2}{l}{\small \textit{Random tail text.}}\\} 
        \tablelasttail{\\ \arrayrulecolor{black} \bottomrule}
        \bottomcaption{Random caption text.}

        \newcounter{rowcounter}
        \begin{supertabular}{p{3cm}|p{9cm}}
            \forloop{rowcounter}{0}{\value{rowcounter} < 70}{line \arabic{rowcounter} & random text \\ \hline }
            last line & random text
        \end{supertabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code from David Carlisle's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52042/15925 as follows

[image: Sample tail]

[image: Sample head]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forloop}

\makeatletter
\let\savedST@cr\ST@cr
\def\ST@cr{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurelet\st@temp\ST@crhline}
\def\ST@crhline{%
  \ifx\st@temp\hline
    \global\let\next@a\hline
    \global\let\next@b\@gobble
  \else
    \global\let\next@a\@gobble
    \global\let\next@b\@empty
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
\next@a
\savedST@cr
\next@b}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\centering
\tablefirsthead{\toprule Row Counter & Random Header \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}

\tablehead{Row Counter & Random Header \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}

\makeatletter
\tabletail{\arrayrulecolor{black}
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \arrayrulecolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{2}{l}{\small \textit{Random
  tail text.}}\\}
\makeatother

\tablelasttail{ \\ \arrayrulecolor{black} \bottomrule}
  \bottomcaption{Random caption text.}

\newcounter{rowcounter}

\begin{supertabular}{p{3cm}|p{9cm}}
  \forloop{rowcounter}{0}{\value{rowcounter} < 70}{line
  \arabic{rowcounter} & random text \\ \hline } last line & random
  text
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the definition of the tail - this a `\bottomrule` without separation.  Alternatively you could set `\arrayrulesep` to `0pt` throughout.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I actually found that answer but didn't know whether it was really related. And I don't know enough Latex understand the code or adjust it.

Comment: I just realized, that the vertical line on the page before (page 1 in the example) is now going down and crossing the table tail. How could I shorten that?

Comment: @ciem I missed that - code now improved to fix this