# how to get rid of extra \hline drawn before start of longtable?

Tags: longtable

Whenever I have a long table

```
\begin{longtable}...\hline
 ....
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
```

That happens to start at top of a page, I see an `\hline` drawn at the end of the previous page. However, if the `longtable` happens to start in the middle of a page, there is no extra `\hline`. I am having hard time telling Latex to please stop doing this since it is very annoying.

Here is a MWE showing `\hline` added before table starts at new page

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{0.5\textwidth} | p{0.5\textwidth}|}\hline
\blindtext
&
\blindtext
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the table starts in the middle of the page (depending on how much text was before it), there is no extra line:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{0.5\textwidth} | p{0.5\textwidth}|}\hline
\blindtext
&
\blindtext
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question: What is the correct way to write `longtable` to prevent the extra line for all different cases?

Comment: Well, not writing `\hline` at the start of the table would be the most reliable way to not get an `\hline` (see how it is on all the lines that have `\begin{longtable} ... \hline`?).  But, second, ditch the `\hlines` entirely, and load `booktabs` and use those lines instead.

Comment: @jon but I want a line at top of the table? I just do not want 2 of them.

Comment: Well, you could use the `needspace` package and do something like `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` before the start of the table.

Comment: if in doubt you could always read the longtable manual which suggests that if you want to stop a page break  before a row or rows of the table then to put those rows into firsthead. (see Christian's answer)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6353/2388 for code for a \nobreakhline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only a 'brute force' solution: Use `\endhead` after the first `\hline`. This 'guarantees' that there's always a `\hline` on table pages other than the first one.

The first one is 'empty' because `longtable` can't break the `\blindtext` paragraph so it is shifted to the next page`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{0.5\textwidth} | p{0.5\textwidth}|}
\hline
\endhead
\blindtext
&
\blindtext
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 as it says in the manual you can use `\endfirsthead` to prevent a page break before any number of initial rows.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd be inclined to use Christian's answer (+1), but, just to provide other ideas, you could use the `needspace` package. E.g.,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%ext
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable,needspace,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\needspace{5\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext

%\needspace{5\baselineskip}
\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{0.5\textwidth} | p{0.5\textwidth}|}\hline
\blindtext
&
\blindtext
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1), but it would use the needspace for any longtable then, I assume?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- Indeed. That's why I commented out the `\needspace` line: in case you only want to do it once/manually, you could use that and not use the `etoolbox` method. I would want to do some testing, I suppose, before I blindly relied on the `etoolbox` method..!

Comment: I see -- well, I can't upvote again ;-)