# How to create a table automatically for a homework in statistics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfkeys

I want to create a long table containing some statistical data, such as the sample, the average, and the variance, etc. I am using the `pgf` package and its various extensions to do this.

Here is a silly MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{document}
\xdef\Sum{0}
\xdef\Rand{0}
\xdef\Avg{0}
\xdef\Var{0}
\xdef\Sq{0}
%\begin{table}[h]
%\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
%\hline
%Trial & Rand & Sum & Sum-of-squares & Average & Variance\\
%\hline\hline
%\noindent Trial Rand Sum Sum-of-squares Average Variance\\
\noindent\foreach \i in {1 ,...,15} {
    %\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
        \pgfmathparse{random(10)}
        \xdef\Rand{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
        \pgfmathparse{\Sum+\Rand}
        \xdef\Sum{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\Sq+\Rand*\Rand}
        \xdef\Sq{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\Sum/\i}
        \xdef\Avg{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\Sq/\i-\Avg*\Avg}
        \xdef\Var{\pgfmathresult}
        \noindent \i,\                             %&%
        \pgfmathparse{\Rand}\pgfmathresult,\    %&%
        \pgfmathparse{\Sum}\pgfmathresult,\      %&%
        \pgfmathparse{\Sq}\pgfmathresult,         %&%
        \pgfmathparse{\Avg}\pgfmathresult,       %&%
        \pgfmathparse{\Var}\pgfmathresult        \\
        %\hline
        }
        %\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is an output (depending on what random numbers you get):

[image]

As you can see, the table is commented out, as I have given up on it. I want to generate a document like this with 1000 pages, and see the computed empirical average and variance.

---

Very closely related:

- [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e)
- [Copy table row n times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times?lq=1)
- [Generate table using the foreach command from pgffor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179978/generate-table-using-the-foreach-command-from-pgffor?lq=1)
- [how to get rid of extra \hline drawn before start of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311338/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-hline-drawn-before-start-of-longtable)

---

Note: this question has been heavily edited due to showing signs of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I will reask problem X in a separate question later.

Comment: While egreg is right that you cannot build a table in a `\foreach` loop, you might want to take a look at the [`pgfplotstable`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable) package. (Or someone with more experience can show us both how to do it.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspected that your question [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/)
was of the XY type.

The usual problem in these cases is that you cannot build a table inside a `\foreach` statement, because table cells form groups. The strategy is to build the table body beforehand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\begin{document}

\def\Sum{0}
\def\Rand{0}
\def\Avg{0}
\def\Var{0}
\def\Sq{0}
\def\TableBody{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,15} {
  %\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
  \pgfmathparse{random(10)}
  \xdef\Rand{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
  \pgfmathparse{\Sum+\Rand}
  \xdef\Sum{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\Sq+\Rand*\Rand}
  \xdef\Sq{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\Sum/\i}
  \xdef\Avg{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\Sq/\i-\Avg*\Avg}
  \xdef\Var{\pgfmathresult}
  \xappto\TableBody{\i & \Rand & \Sum & \Sq & \Avg & \Var \noexpand\\}
}

\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
\toprule
Trial & Rand & Sum & Sum-of-squares & Average & Variance \\
\midrule
\TableBody
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what I get with `longtable` and 500 draws.

[image]

Comment: I will edit my question to match your answer to problem  Y, and after more empirical testing I hope to reask question X again separately. Related: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in `pgfplotstable` but here is an idea to build upon.

To get the entries to align prettier, see [Q131081](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131081).

(I find `pgfplotstable` overly complicated and it surely doesn't help that the manual repeats parts of the PGFmanual …)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgfplotstable}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\pgfplotstableset{
  duck ini/.style={columns={Trial,Rand}},
  duck table/.style={
    columns={Trial,Rand,Sum,Sq,Avg,Var},
    set column name/.list={Sq:Sum-of-squared, Avg:Average, Var:Variance},
    every head row/.append style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.append style={after row=\bottomrule},
    set column/.list={Avg:prec=1, Var:prec=2}},
  set column name/.style args={#1:#2}{columns/#1/.append style={column name={#2}}},
  set column/.style args={#1:#2}{columns/#1/.append style={#2}},
  set expr/.style args={#1=#2}{create on use/#1/.style={create col/expr={#2}}}}
\pgfset{number format/prec/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill, precision={#1}}}
\pgfplotstableset{set expr/.list={Trial=\pgfplotstablerow+1,Rand=int(rnd*11)}}
\newcommand*\addmyusualcolumns[1]{%
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{Rand}}]                           {Sum} #1
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\pgfmathaccuma+\thisrow{Rand}*\thisrow{Rand}}]            {Sq}  #1
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\thisrow{Sum}/\thisrow{Trial}}]                           {Avg} #1
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr={\thisrow{Sq}/\thisrow{Trial}-\thisrow{Avg}*\thisrow{Avg}}]{Var} #1}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablenew[duck ini]{15}\t
\addmyusualcolumns\t
\pgfplotstabletypeset[duck table]\t

\pgfplotstablenew[duck ini]{30}\T
\addmyusualcolumns\T
\pgfplotstabletypeset[duck table]\T
\end{document}
```