# Reverse engineering a table: how can I make a table that looks like this?

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I'm new to Latex and was wondering how I can make a table that looks like the one below? I would be extremely grateful for any help.

[image]

EDIT: Below is a MWE that is nearly the same as what I'm trying to create. The problem is that the Standard Deviation column title width isn't as wide as in the table I'm trying to create.

```
% From: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}

\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\renewcommand*\rot[2]{\multicolumn{1}{R{#1}{#2}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l | l l | c c c c c} 
  &  \rot{90}{1em}{Mean} & \rot{90}{1em}{Standard Deviation} & \rot{90}{1em}{Min} & \rot{90}{1em}{Q1} & \rot{90}{1em}{Median} & \rot{90}{1em}{Q3} & \rot{90}{1em}{Max} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
 Thing & 65.5 & 11 & 15 & 45 & 50 & 67 & 76\\ [0ex]
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You will be surprised how much LaTeX is capable of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311884/how-to-create-a-table-automatically-for-a-homework-in-statistics

Comment: Hi @Matsmath While that's pretty cool, I'm not interested in using Latex to derive the statistical information for my table - I can do that myself. All I'm interested in is creating a table that looks like the one above.

Comment: I can help you in this, however now I'm to lazy for retyping your table from scratch ... Can you provide, small, complete document, which can be compiled and contain your table? And, welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: @Zarko No problem. Please see the edit to my post above.

Comment: An MWE should compile. Please always post complete code! (Unless the problem is that it doesn't compile - then it should not compile with the error you want help with. ;) )

Comment: @cfr OK, got it :) Does anyone have an answer to the question I asked in my comment to Bernard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple with `\rothead` from `makecell`. I propose two versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % To align the numbers later on
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Deviation }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Deviation}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}} \toprule
  \rothead{Mean} & \rothead{Standard Deviation}& \rothead{Min} &  \rothead{Q1} &  \rothead{Median} &  \rothead{Q3} &  \rothead{Max}\\
  \midrule
  76.3 & 15.3 & 35.0 & 72.5 & 75.0 & 52.5 & 100\\
  69.1 & 17.2 & 30.0 & 32.5 & 70.0 & 80.0 & 100 \\
  72.7 & 16.5 & 30.0 & 65.0 & 72.5 & 82.5 & 100 \\
  \midrule
  73.1 & 14.7 & 27.5 & 70.0 & 75.0 & 80.0 & 97.5 \\
  71.4 & 12.7 & 40.0 & 67.5 & 75.0 &77.5 & 87.5 \\
  72.3 & 13.7 & 27.5 & 67.5 & 75.50 & 80.0 & 97.5 \\
        \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\renewcommand\cellrotangle{45}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{-6pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}} 
  \rothead{~\\[2ex]Mean} & \rothead{Standard Deviation}& \rothead{~\\[2ex]Min} &  \rothead{~\\[3ex]Q1} &  \rothead{~\\[3ex]Median} &  \rothead{~\\[3ex]Q3} &   \rothead{~\\[2ex]Max}\\
  \toprule
  76.3 & 15.3 & 35.0 & 72.5 & 75.0 & 52.5 & 100\\
  69.1 & 17.2 & 30.0 & 32.5 & 70.0 & 80.0 & 100 \\
  72.7 & 16.5 & 30.0 & 65.0 & 72.5 & 82.5 & 100 \\
  \midrule
  73.1 & 14.7 & 27.5 & 70.0 & 75.0 & 80.0 & 97.5 \\
  71.4 & 12.7 & 40.0 & 67.5 & 75.0 &77.5 & 87.5 \\
  72.3 & 13.7 & 27.5 & 67.5 & 75.50 & 80.0 & 97.5 \\
        \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard. Thanks for this - really nice. Is there a fainter version of `\midrule`? I'd like to add some kind of separator to the top of the third row. I tried using `\hline` but the adjustment didn't look right when next to the midrules. What would you suggest I use?

Comment: Do you mean with a thinner rule? You can use thickness as an optional argument of \midrule, or  use `\cmidrule{1-7}`. In addition, \cmidrule can be trimmed on the left, or on the right, or both. You may write for instance: `\cmidrule(lr){1-7}`.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks again @Bernard. Another question: How can I change the thickness of the horizontal lines?

Comment: Do as I said in my previous comment: `\midrule[some thickness]` or `\cmidrule(lr)[some thickness]{1-7}` for instance. Or change in the preamble the default values for top and bottom rules (`\heavyrulewidth` is `0.08em`), for midrules (`\lightrulewidth` = `0.05em`)  or for cmidrules (`\cmidrulewidth`= `0.03em`).

Comment: Apologies @Bernard. I meant to write *vertical lines*. I am very grateful for you help thus far.

Comment: I forgot to mention you definitely should not use vertical lines for such a table if you want it it to look professional, and in any case they would not intersect the horizontal lines of booktabs. If you absolutely want or need to do it, you should use the small `boldline` package, from the  `shipunov` bundle, or use the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands from `makecell`, and make vertical rules with, for instance, `!{\vrule width 1pt}` between two columns instead of `|` to have a vertical rule 1 pt thick.