# Tex: longtable page break at specific rows only

Tags: longtable

My table is logically divided by 2 rows in a group. I want the page break occurs only after the last row in the group. How I can do that with longtable?
In the example below page break happens on "bit 6"

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={160mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\date{}

\begin{document}


\subsubsection{SOME\_REGISTER, 0x100}\label{some_register-0x100}

Some register for XXX

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline
{\bf Bit Position} & {\bf Field Name} & {\bf Permissions} & {\bf Reset Value} & {\bf Field Attributes} \\\hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline {\bf Bit Position} & {\bf Field Name} & {\bf Permissions} & {\bf Reset Value} & {\bf Field Attributes} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
0        & Reserved   & --          & --          & \\\hline 
1         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline
2         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline
3         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline
4         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline
5         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline
6         & FIELD1\_NAME & RW & 0x0 & \\*\hline 
             & \multicolumn{4}{|p{.85\textwidth}|}{
Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

Line1
Line1

} \\\hline

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\* `does not give you the desired result since it is followed by an `\hline`. Pagrebreaks are generally allowed at `\hline`. To change this, you can use the approach presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6353/134144

Comment: Why use you `\bf` instead of `\textbf{}` text mode or `\mathbf{}` in math-mode?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\\` to allow for pagebreaks after this specific row. Use `\\*` instead 
to disallow page breaks.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work - the page break occurs right after the `\\*`

Comment: Please edit your question and add a compilable example document that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0):

As stated by leandriis, this post helped me to implement correct page breaks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107893/209519