# Control pagebreak longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable, page-breaking

Requirements:
A longtable List A for n lists (List B) (longtable to get one design alignments).
Generic term is List A, which appears as title on every new page as generic term

Longtable rows represent independent little n lists (List B). Their structure is always the same 1) Business row 2) Column description 3) n row entries. The length of those little lists differs. Such a list should never be broken (by pagebreak). Consequence: The start of such a little list ( 1)+2)+3) ) appears always on top of a new page.

> List A                                 page 1
>
> > List B
> >
> > > ```
> > > Header (2 rows)
> > > 1 - n rows
> > > ```
> >
> > List B
> >
> > > ```
> > > Header (2 rows)
> > > 1 - n rows
> > > .
> > > .
> > > ```
>
> List A                                 page 2
>
> > List B
> >
> > > ```
> > > Header (2 rows)                         every time at first after pagebreak
> > > 1 - n rows                      must follow the header NEVER pagebreak (except of last row of this list B)
> > > ```
> >
> > List B
> >
> > > ```
> > > Header (2 rows)
> > > 1 - n rows
> > >
> > > .
> > > ```

What I have reached is the correct placement of the "generic term" s.a. and the unique appearance. Has anyone a solution for the controlled pagebreak not to separate a List B as shown in the output?

```
    %\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA not recommended with usage of fancyhdr
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[top=1.0cm,right=1cm,left=1cm,bottom=1cm,headheight=50pt,includeheadfoot,headsep=20pt,]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{} % clears all fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    
    \definecolor{ctaggreen}{HTML}{330066}
    \setlength\headheight{57pt} % to prevent warning of fancyhdr
    
    \cfoot{\colorbox{ctaggreen}{\parbox[b][0.20cm][c]{1.0cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}}
    
    \lhead{\raisebox{-2mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{6.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testlogo.png}}}}
    \rhead{\raisebox{-2mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{-6.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testlogo.png}}}}
    \chead{\raisebox{3mm}{\colorbox{ctaggreen}{\parbox[b][1.00cm][c]{6.0cm}{\large\centering\textcolor{black}{\sffamily \bfseries{Phone list} \\ [-0.20cm] \footnotesize{voor Medewerkers}%
    }%end parbox
    }%raisebox
    }%endcolorbox
    }% end chead
    }% end of ???. without: error paragraph ended before ychead...
    
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \begin{document}
    \Large %quick and dirty
    \sffamily
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[h]{ll@{}lr@{ - }l}% 
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{next page continues}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline\hline % two horiz. lines at the end of table
    \endlastfoot
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %first tab row
    %
    % Headline
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    % Column desc
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    % Rows
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline% Column desc
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\* 
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\*  [1cm] %
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\* [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\*  [1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\ \hline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \hline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\*  [1cm] 
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Output:
[[image: p. 1][1]]
[image: p. 2]

[image: p. 3]

Comment: unrelated to the question but `[h]` longtable does not have an h option.

Comment: `longtable` allows pagebreaks at a `\hline` which is why your panel is split between pages although you used `\\* ` prior the the `\hline`. See also: [How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6350/134144)

Comment: @David Carlisle; I have removed the "h", reaction remains equal.

Comment: @leandris: all rows now " \\*", except the ones with "business"  (the headline of the List B, where pagebreak is ok). All "\hline" removed. No success.

Comment: Regarding "except the ones with "business" (the headline of the List B, where pagebreak is ok).": I think, you want to use `\\*` after this specific line as well and use `\\ ` on the line right before "Business..." in order to keep "Business"  and the following rows on the same page, while allowing a page break right before "Business...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I have built in the macro `\nobreakhline`. Additionaly corrected the setting of `\\`, `\\*`, `\\* \nobreakhline`. And it works! Many thanks to everyone who shared their knowledge here.

The code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[top=1.0cm,right=1cm,left=1cm,bottom=1cm,headheight=50pt,includeheadfoot,headsep=20pt,]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{} % clears all fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    
    \definecolor{ctaggreen}{HTML}{330066}
    \setlength\headheight{57pt} % to prevent warning of fancyhdr
    
    \cfoot{\colorbox{ctaggreen}{\parbox[b][0.20cm][c]{1.0cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}}
    
    \lhead{\raisebox{-2mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{6.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testlogo.png}}}}
    \rhead{\raisebox{-2mm}{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace*{-6.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testlogo.png}}}}
    \chead{\raisebox{3mm}{\colorbox{ctaggreen}{\parbox[b][1.00cm][c]{6.0cm}{\large\centering\textcolor{black}{\sffamily \bfseries{Phone list} \\ [-0.20cm] \footnotesize{voor Medewerkers}%
    }%end parbox
    }%raisebox
    }%endcolorbox
    }% end chead
    }% end of ???. without: error paragraph ended before ychead...
    
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    
    %%%
    \makeatletter
    \def\nobreakhline{%
      \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
        \penalty\@M
        \futurelet\@let@token\LT@@nobreakhline}
    \def\LT@@nobreakhline{%
      \ifx\@let@token\hline
        \global\let\@gtempa\@gobble
        \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip\doublerulesep}% <-- change here
      \else
        \global\let\@gtempa\@empty
        \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty\@M\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}% <-- change here
      \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
      \multispan\LT@cols
         \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
      \noalign{\LT@sep}%
      \multispan\LT@cols
         \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
      \noalign{\penalty\@M}%
      \@gtempa}
    \makeatother
    %%%
    \begin{document}
    \Large %quick and dirty
    \sffamily
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[]{ll@{}lr@{ - }l}% 
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{next page continues}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline\hline % two horiz. lines at the end of table
    \endlastfoot
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %first tab row
    %
    % Headline
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline
    % Column desc
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    % Rows
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline% Column desc
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\* \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\* 
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\  [1cm] %
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\*\nobreakhline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\* \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Herbert}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\*  \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    B\"uro & 71073 & 707 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\* 
    Dimitri & 20573 & 070 37 10 &   & \\*  
    Dimitri & 2060 & 00 57 71 71 &   & \\*  
    Herbert & 2073 & 272 25 75 & 00:00 & 00:30  \\*  
    Alma & 20516 & 655 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\*  
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Johannes & 20520 & 700 37 00 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\*
    Georg & 2060 & 706 10 60 &    & \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Gottfried \& Shirin}}  Operating times (00:00)07:00 - 16:30\\*  \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Shirin & 20523 & 370 70 00 & 00:00 & 00:20  \\* 
    Jessy & 2077 & 076 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\*  
    Leo & 2077 & 525 03 71 & 15:00  & 15:30\\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Business Jorge}}  Operating times 07:30 - 16:30\\*  \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} &    & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Jorge     & 2072  & 263 30 26 & 12:00  & 13:00  \\* 
    Gabi  & 20525 & 733 76 75 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Quintus & 2070  & 013 07 23 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\*  
    Sokrates   & 20522 & 730 50 30 & 12:00  & 13:00 \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\*  \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\[1cm] 
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Pascal} \Smiley}   Operating times& & \\*  \nobreakhline
    Contact & {Phone} & & Break from&to \\* \nobreakhline
    Pascal & 2072 & 730 05 75 &  &   \\[1cm] 
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Output with pdflatex:

[image: p.1]
[image: p.2]
[image: p.3]